# R dictionary: create a many-to-one mapping

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

Consider the following MWE in a text mining exercise, using R{tm}:
Toyota has several SUV models in the US.`models<-c("highlander","land cruiser","rav4","sequoia","4runner")`. The general media refers to these not as "toyota rav4" (corpus already transformed to lower case) but as "rav4". To get a single column of toyota suvs in a DocumentTermMatrix, i need to convert all these brands into one generic "toyota_suv". What I am doing now is to repeat `mycorpus<-tm_map(mycorpus, gsub, pattern="rav4", replacement="toyota_suv")` for length(models). A hack would be to set up `model_names<-rep("toyota_suv",length(models))` and get on with life. How can I set up a dictionary with many-to-one mapping, so that all `models` are replaced with 'toyota_suv' in one expression? Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a vectorized substitution function.  The `stringi` package offers such a function with the `stri_replace_all` family of functions.  Here, I'm using `stri_replace_all_fixed`, but adjust case sensitivity and other options as needed.

```
library(tm)
library(stringi)

toyota_suvs <- c("highlander","land cruiser","rav4","sequoia","4runner")

tm_map(toyCorp, stri_replace_all_fixed,
    pattern = toyota_suvs, replacement = "toyota_suv",
    vectorize_all = FALSE)
```

data:

```
toyExample <- c("you don't know about the rav4, John Snow",
    "the highlander is a great car",
    "I want a land cruiser")

toyCorp <- Corpus(VectorSource(toyExample))
```

Comment: Thanks. without opening another question, how does this compare with a dictionary mapping in terms of time?

Comment: @Pradeep I don't know.  I think you would need to do a bit more leg work in providing an example set of documents and exactly what sort of output you're looking to get.  If you are looking to change the input documents themselves (before corpus creation), it's going to be hard to beat using `stringi` directly:  `stri_replace_all_fixed(toyExample, pattern = toyota_suvs, replacement = "toyota_suv", vectorize_all = FALSE)`.  Feed that into `tm_map` is going to slow things down considerably.

Comment: If time is an important consideration, I would move away from the `tm` package.  You could maybe try `quanteda`, which has a dictionary method, however, I have not been able to make it work with directly with multi-words like "land cruiser".  So, some additional processing would be required.

Comment: Thank you much for your comments. I tried `quanteda` and dropped it because it does too many things under the hood (step `dfm`). Sometimes, i need to poke what's going on at each step and tune the dictionary structure accordingly.